No response from List permissions for a site using Microsoft Graph API
We use the graph API from Microsoft to get the details about site, drives, files, folder, etc.
The graph API works as expected and returns the results for those queries.
However, If I try to get the permissions using /sites/{site_id}/permissions endpoint I get below:
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#sites('{site_id}')/permissions",
    "value": []
}

Sites.FullControl.All permission with Admin Consent is also assigned before using this endpoint.

This is the expected behavior. /sites/{site_id}/permissions will return permissions set with Entra ID permissions, not members or visitors of the SharePoint site:

If successful, this method returns a 200 OK response code and collection of Permission resources in the response body.
Effective sharing permissions of a DriveItem can come from two sources:

Sharing permissions applied directly on the DriveItem itself
Sharing permissions inherited from the DriveItem's ancestors


Documentation: List sharing permissions on a driveItem
Source: Graph API site permissions returning empty list

/sites/{site_id}/permissions returns a 200 OK status but doesn't provide any data. If no results are returned, how can we fetch the site permissions? Our goal is to determine the permissions assigned to each site, so we can manage them as entitlements for users or groups

With SharePoint REST API, not with Graph API. So I think this is another question. Please accept this one and search or create a new one.
